# openconnect cannot connect to Anyconnect VPN group using -g

Tags: vpn, openconnect

I am using `openconnect` to connect to a VPN. When starting the client as `sudo openconnect -v -u anaphory vpn-gw1.somewhere.net`, I am able to connect after entering the GROUP and Password.

```
# openconnect -v -u anaphory vpn-gw1.somewhere.net
[…]
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
GROUP: [Anyconnect-VPN|CLUSTER-DLCE|Clientless]:CLUSTER-DLCE
POST https://vpn-gw1.somewhere.net
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
[…]
```

However, when I specify that same group name on the command line, the connection fails with an “Invalid host entry” message.

```
# openconnect -v -g CLUSTER-DLCE -u anaphory vpn-gw1.somewhere.net
[…]
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
Password:XML POST enabled
Invalid host entry. Please re-enter.
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

Do I need to do any magic to the group name, or how do I find out how to make this work?

Comment: Did you meanwhile find a solution?

Comment: related question [openconnect VPN works in KDE NetworkManager widget but not on command line](http://serverfault.com/q/627530/125845)

Answer (score 34):

Try `--authgroup` instead of `-g`

```
openconnect -v --authgroup CLUSTER-DLCE -u anaphory vpn-gw1.somewhere.net
```

Regards

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: @AndyS and @stambata: Thanks for your kind help! How can I use this command if the group name contains empty spaces between words, for example a group name like: "tunnel Company XYZ"? I can not write either `authgroup=tunnel Company XYZ` nor `authgroup="tunnel Company XYZ". Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @AndyS and @stambata: Just for additional information, the group names are provided in the user prompt in that way: `GROUP: [tunnel Company XYZ|tunnel all]:` - How can I type this into the `openconnect`-command?

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact, the not answer given by user2000606 leads to success.

The HTTP messages sent to the ASA differ, depending on how you select a group and VPN gateways can be picky about it.

This is my basic call to `openconnect`

```
openconnect -v --printcookie --dump-http-traffic \
 --passwd-on-stdin \
 -u johnsmith \
 vpn.ssl.mydomain.tld
```

Issuing this command and providing my desired VPN group after being prompted results in the followin HTTP chat (I only included the seemingly relevant parts of the XML documents):

```
[Certificate error, I tell openconnect to continue]
Me >> ASA:  POST / HTTP/1.1
            [...]<group-access>https://vpn.ssl.mydomain.tld</group-access>
ASA << ME:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Me >> ASA:  POST / HTTP/1.1
            [...]<group-access>https://vpn.ssl.mydomain.tld/</group-access><group-select>AnyConnect-MyGroup</group-select>
ASA << ME:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Me >> ASA:  POST / HTTP/1.1
            [...]<auth><username>johnsmith</username><password>secret</password></auth><group-select>AnyConnect-MyGroup</group-select>
ASA << ME:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Notice the `group-select`-groups and that all requests are  `POST / HTTP/1.1`. The same result is achieved by providing `--authgroup AnyConnect-MyGroup` with the basic call to `openconnect`.

When using `-g AnyConnect-MyGroup` instead of  `--authgroup AnyConnect-MyGroup` the following happens:

```
Me >> ASA:  POST /AnyConnect-MyGroup HTTP/1.1
            [...]<group-access>https://vpn.ssl.mydomain.tld/AnyConnect-MyGroup</group-access>
ASA << ME:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
            [...] <error id="91" param1="" param2="">Invalid host entry. Please re-enter.</error>
```

Notice that this time we don't tell the server `group-select` but simply squeeze in our group name with `group-access` and the HTTP request. The same negative result is provoked when adding the group name to the gateway address, i.e. using `vpn.ssl.mydomain.tld/AnyConnect-MyGroup` as the last line of the basic call to `openconnect`.